# How to limit a query by column value

Tags: mysql, sql, graphql

Following query...

```
SELECT event_id, user_id FROM EventUser WHERE user_id IN (1, 2)
```

...gives me the following result:

```
+----------+---------+
| event_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        3 |       1 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        1 |       1 |
|        5 |       1 |
|        4 |       1 |
|        6 |       1 |
|        4 |       2 |
|        2 |       2 |
|        1 |       2 |
|        5 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

Now, I want to modify the above query so that I only get for example two rows for each user_id, eg:

```
+----------+---------+
| event_id | user_id |
+----------+---------+
|        3 |       1 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        4 |       2 |
|        5 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

I am thinking about something like this, which of course does not work:

```
SELECT event_id, user_id FROM EventUser WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) LIMIT 2 by user_id
```

Ideally, this should work with offsets as well because I want to use it for paginations.

For performance reasons it is essential to use the `WHERE user_id IN (1, 2)` part of the query.

Comment: How do you know which two events you want for each user_id?

Comment: Also: this would be easy in any modern database engine, either via APPLY/LATERAL JOIN or ROW_NUMBER() windowing function. Sadly, MySql hasn't really be a "modern" database for more than a decade, and supports neither.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn What engines would you recommend?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The first n ordered by the event_id with an offset m, I guess

Comment: Any of Sql Server, Oracle, Postgresql would do this. But it seems late in a project to change platforms.

Answer (score 0):

One method -- assuming you have at least two rows for each user -- would be:

```
(select min(event_id) as event_id, user_id
 from t
 where user in (1, 2)
 group by user_id
) union all
(select max(event_id) as event_id, user_id
 from t
 where user in (1, 2)
 group by user_id
);
```

Admittedly, this is not a "general" solution, but it might be the simplest solution for what you want.

If you want the two biggest or smallest, then an alternative also works:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.user_id in (1, 2) and
      t.event_id >= (select t2.event_id
                     from t t2
                     where t2.user_id = t.user_id
                     order by t2.event_id desc
                     limit 1, 1
                    );
```

Comment: To my understanding this only works for a limit of two rows per user, right? I need a more general solution for n rows, though.

Comment: @HansMu158 . . . This answers your question, which is to get two rows per user.  In my opinion, modifying the second is trivial to get more rows, but if you don't see how, ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic example for such problems, Please note that this example is working in SQL Server, could not try on mysql for now. Please let me know how it works.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
    (
      number INT,
      score INT
    )

INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 1, 100)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 2, 100)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 2, 120)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 2, 110)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 3, 120)
INSERT  INTO mytable VALUES  ( 3, 150)

SELECT *
FROM mytable m
WHERE 
        (
            SELECT  COUNT(*) 
            FROM    mytable  m2
            WHERE   m2.number = m.number AND 
                    m2.score >= m.score
        ) <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT event_id, user_id 
FROM (
      SELECT event_id, user_id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) AS row_num 
      FROM EventUser WHERE user_id in (1,2)) WHERE row_num <= n;
```

And `n` can be whatever

Comment: The question is tagged MySql, and MySql doesn't support windowing functions like row_number()

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number ?

Comment: has MySql 8 actually released yet? They're still in "release candidate" phase, not production.

Answer (score 0):

Later but help uses a derived table and the cross join.
For the example in this post the query will be this:

```
SELECT 
@row_number:=CASE
    WHEN @user_no = user_id 
      THEN 
          @row_number + 1
      ELSE 
           1
    END AS num,
@user_no:=user_id userid, event_id 
FROM
EventUser,
(SELECT @user_no:=0,@row_number:=0) as t
group by user_id,event_id
having num < 3;
```

More information in [this link](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number).